# Integrability of a function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Show that the function is integrable on $[0,2]$
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1-x & x<1 \\
x^2-2x+1 & x \geq 1
\end{array}\right.$$

What conditions need to be checked in order for it to be integrable? I'm guessing the integral has to be a finite value, but how do I compute the integral over an interval, since I have a conditional function? Is the integral equal to:
$$\int _0^2f\left(x\right)dx=\int _0^1f\left(x\right)dx+\int _1^2f\left(x\right)dx\:=\int _0^1\left(1-x\right)dx+\int _1^2\left(x^2-2x+1\right)dx$$

And I just compute that and see if I get a finite value? Or should I check whether to see the function is continuous?

Comment: Usually when we say $f$ is "integrable" on $[0,2]$, we mean that we first take the absolute value of $f$, and then integrate that over $[0,2]$, and this integral should be finite for $f$ to be "integrable".  So $\int \limits_{0}^{2} |f(x)| dx = \int \limits_{0}^{1} |1 - x| dx + \int \limits_{1}^{2} |x^{2} - 2x + 1| dx$.  Now, since on $[0,1]$, $1 - x$ is always positive, then $|1 - x| = 1 - x$, so the integrand in the first integral becomes $1 - x$.  Also since $x^{2} - 2x + 1 = (x - 1)^{2}$, and anything squared is always positive, then $|(x - 1)^{2}| = (x - 1)^{2}$, so the second integral...

Comment: ...just becomes the integral of $(x - 1)^{2}$.  So, you can now compute these integrals, and if they are both finite, then their sum is finite, so then $f$ is integrable over $[0,2]$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I needed to use the absolute value of $f$. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and thus Riemann integrable.

Comment: Does that mean that if a function isn't continuous, it isn't integrable? What would I need to do to check whether a non-continuous function is integrable?

Comment: Nope bounded functions with at most countable discontinuities are R-integrable

Comment: Also, did I compute that integral right? $\int _0^2f\left(x\right)dx=...$

Comment: Yes it is correct